# Combine: Casting AnyPublisher<Void, Error> to AnyPublisher<"OurType", Error>

Tags: swift, combine

I need to test the code:

```
func ourFunc() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
       model: OurModel = OurModel()
       Just(model).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

An error occurs:
`Cannot convert value of type OurModel to expected type Void`

How we can typecast `OurModel` type to `Void`?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? Converting a model that you've just created inside a fun to `Void` does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: You can't *typecast* a generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any sense in it. Can you explain further?

There's no point in mapping it…

```swift
Just(model).map { _ in } .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

…because it doesn't matter what the original `Output` was. It's all going to become `()`.

```swift
Just(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```